# Is there any way to ellipsize the hint in the EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view

The length of hint in my EditText is bit longer than the width of ET view. So how can i set marquee attribute to ET view. I have tried setting it, but the app crashes giving the error : **E/AndroidRuntime(2095): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EditText cannot use the ellipsize mode TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE**

I have gone through the docs of ellipsize method, but not getting what i am supposed to do.I have tried these two steps :

1) 
    `android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"`

2) `android:maxLines="1"
   android:scrollHorizontally="true"`

Docs of ellipsize method:
**Causes words in the text that are longer than the view is wide to be ellipsized instead of broken in the middle. You may also want to setSingleLine() or setHorizontallyScrolling(boolean) to constrain the text to a single line. Use null to turn off ellipsizing. If setMaxLines(int) has been used to set two or more lines, only END and MARQUEE are supported (other ellipsizing types will not do anything).**

Let me know what modification has to be done so that it works right.Thank you

Comment: Hi @DJphy I'm facing the same issue as my app supports localisation so for some locale edit text hint is bigger than edit text.
have you found any  solution for this? your help will be appreciated.

Comment: @umesh all i found was you cannot have a marquee ellipsize for the edit text but you can have **ellipsize at the end**.
**etView.setHint(hintMsg);
etView.setSingleLine(true);
etView.setMaxLines(1);
etView.setEllipsize(android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);**

This will now cut off the extra hint text(if hint text length is greater than the width of the edit text view) and put 3 dots at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I think marquee doesn't works for EditText.You can use other attribute to ellipsize hint if it is getting longer than the size of editText.

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Answer (score 2):

@DJphy - I found a solution no need to set ellipsis. when you are setting the string to edit text just set simple HTML attributes to string.
Played with some HTML tricks and it worked for me.
ex:- 
nameEdittxt.setHint(Html.fromHtml(`"<small><small><small>" + getString(R.string.enter_name) + "</small></small></small>"`));

This will help to set hint smaller and Edit text size as normal you had set as fontsize.
Look at my attachments - 
Before setting HTML attributes to hint - 
[image]

- After setting HTML attributes to hint - 
  [image]

Comment: This is something to check out for.. I will give it a try

Comment: android:ellipsize="end" not working for some device, but this solution work, Thanks!